# How to pass Model and some form data to controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to pass the entire model with some more data from the current form using an ActionLink but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is my View:

```
@model BitcoinRedeemPage.Controllers.BitcoinTransactionViewModel


<form action="/DepositDetails/Send" method="post">
    <input id="walletAddress" type="text" name="walletAddress" />

    @Html.ActionLink("Send", "DepositDetails", "Send", new { /* Here i want to send the current @Model and the walletAddress form field value */ } , null)
</form>
```

The Controller function header which is supposed to receive this data looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Send(string walletAddress, BitcoinTransactionViewModel transaction)
```

Please help :)

Comment: Is there some particular reason you need to pass the whole Model in a link instead of regular form fields?

Comment: Yes because i need to pass it back if it fails during validation on server side

Comment: You don't need to stuff it in a link for that and you're just going to make things much more convoluted for yourself.  You accepted @ataravati's answer so obviously you're planning on changing your approach.

Answer (score 4):

There are so many things wrong with your code that I don't know where to begin with.

1. You don't post your Model back to the Controller using an `ActionLink`. You should use a submit button in your form to submit it to the server (Controller).
2. Use Html Helpers instead of HTML tags.
3. Your ViewModel should be under ViewModels folder and namespace, not under Controllers.
4. And, if you want to submit additional data along with your Model,
   you should add them as properties to your View Model.

Here is what your View should look like:

```
@model BitcoinRedeemPage.ViewModels.BitcoinTransactionViewModel

@using(Html.BeginForm("Send", "DepositDetails"))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.WallterAddress)

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

And, in your Controller you'll have:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Send(BitcoinTransactionViewModel transaction)
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Is there a way to see the code of those helpers? i want more control over the code and not to be so tied up with the infrastructure.

Comment: You can download the MVC source code if you want to see what the helpers are doing.

Comment: Here you can find the source code: http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/

Comment: The entire viewmodel isn't being sent back to the controller... Do i need to add hidden fields that contain the viewmodel's properties to make it work?

Comment: I've unchecked your answer because now the controller is not getting the entire viewmodel when the form is submitting. Am i missing something?

Comment: Yes, you need to use Hidden field that properties that are not changed by the user. Post your View and your ViewModel, so I can tell you if you are missing something.